# How to and where to use gethtml() in grapejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, backend, grapesjs

I have to get the backend code generated by grapesjs. How do I use editor.getHtml() to get the backend code? Where do I put it in the code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.